# How to remove item in an array stored locally with event delegation?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

I want to remove an item that i click from the DOM and from an array, i got the first part done, its getting removed nicely, but in the array, im not sure how to target that certain item's id and instead it's just deleting first thing in the array ?

I would rather appreciate a hint than a full answer please :)

Thanks in advance
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE="html">
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c6015819ca.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>To do app in JS</title>
    <h1 class='title'>To-do app in JS</h1>
  </head>
<body>
    <div class='app'>
        <div class='header'>
            <img src="./images/header.jpg"/>
            <div id="date">DATA</div>
            <div id="time"></div>
        </div>
        <div id='listTop'>
            <i class="fas fa-sync-alt" id="clear"></i>
            <p id='pClear'>Clear All</p>
        </div>
        <ul id='list'>

        </ul>
        <div class="footer">
            <i class="fas fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true" id='addButton'></i>
            <input type="text" id='itemInput' placeholder="Add a to-do" />
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="./index.js"></script>

</body>
```

JS

```
function addToDo(toDo, id, done, trash) {
    const text =`
    <li class="item">
        <i class="far fa-check-circle" id='jobComplete'></i>
            <div class="description">${toDo}</div>
        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt" id='deleteItem'></i>
    </li>`;
    const position = "beforeend";
    list.insertAdjacentHTML(position, text);
}

document.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        const toDo = input.value;
            if(toDo) {
                addToDo(toDo, id, false, false);
                LIST.push(
                    {
                        name: toDo,
                        id: id,
                        done: false,
                        trash: false
                    }

                );
                console.log(LIST);
                id++;
                input.value = '';

            }
        }
})

clear.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('list');
    list.innerHTML = "";
    LIST = [];
    id = 0;
    console.log(LIST);
    }
)

document.getElementById("addButton").addEventListener('click', (event) =>{
    const toDo = input.value;   
    if(toDo) {
        addToDo(toDo, id, false, false);
        LIST.push(
            {
                name: toDo,
                id: id,
                done: false,
                trash: false
            }

        );
        id++;
        input.value = '';

    }
})

function jobCheck () {

};


list.addEventListener("click", event => {
    if(event.target.className === "fas fa-trash-alt" ) {
        trash = true;
        event.target.parentNode.remove();
        LIST.splice(event.target, 1);
        console.log(LIST);

    }
});
```

Comment: this is unclear, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: where is your HTML? where is your `LIST`?

Comment: Use a `Set` instead of an array (pseudo code): `var x = new Set(); x.add(event.target); if (x.has(event.target)) { ... } x.delete(event.target);`

Comment: Right, as it seems there was not enough information, so i just updated code in the question